# Java - Regular Expressions

Tags: java, regex

In Java I am currently learning about the regular expressions syntax, but I don't really understand the RE patterns...

What I know is patterns have group length and for the string pattern below there is a length of 3.

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class RE {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String line = "Foo123";
        String pattern = "(.*)(\\d+)(.*)"; //RE Syntax I get stuck on.

        Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
        Matcher m = r.matcher(line);

        if (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group(0));
            System.out.println(m.group(1));
            System.out.println(m.group(2));
            System.out.println(m.group(3));
        }
    }
}
```

I would be like it if someone would explain to me what this expression does what does more than one group do etc...

Comment: Read about [capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

Comment: And here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html

Comment: So what does + do? It says that "Matches 1 or more of the previous thing" but when I take it out, it makes no difference?

Comment: Example:  `\\d+@` matches 123@, `\\d@` matches 5@ but not more than one digit followed by @.

Comment: And also, if pattern was \\bcat\\b and line was cat cat cattie cat, why does the 2nd part \\b allow only full matches of cat?

Comment: Because that's what `\\b` means.

Answer (score 3):

Group 0 contains the entire match and group 1, 2, 3 contains corresponding captured characters.

Input string: `Foo123`

Regex : `(.*)(\d+)(.*)`

The first `.*` in the first capturing group matches all the characters upto the last. Then it backtracks until it finds a digit. The reason for backtracking is in-order to find a match . And the corresponding digit would be captured by the group 2 (*last digit*). There is nothing left after all the digits , so you got an empty string inside group 3.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/nL5yL3/33)

Comment: Good explanation about the internals.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an explanation:

```
(       : start capture group 1
    .*  : 0 or more any character
)       : end group
(       : start capture group 2
    \\d+: 1 or more digit
)       : end group
(       : start capture group 3
    .*  : 0 or more any character
)       : end group
```

This regex matches for example:

- `123`
- `abc456kljh`
- `:.?222`

Answer (score 1):

```
String line = "Foo123";
String pattern = "(.*)(\\d+)(.*)"; 
// (take any character - zero or more) // (digits one or more) // (take any character - zero or more)
```

So in the above case we have 3 groups captured. One with any character zero or more (greedy - [can read at this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions)), then we have digits with \d pattern + corresponds to one or more.

Answer (score 0):

**[(.*)(\\d+)(.*)](http://regexr.com/3a23t)**

> You can hover over the regular expression you will get an explanation of that part.

```
1st Capturing group (.*)
  .* matches any character (except newline)
  Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible
2nd Capturing group (\d+)
  \\ matches the character \ literally
  d+ matches the character d literally (case sensitive)
  Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible
3rd Capturing group (.*)
  .* matches any character (except newline)
  Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible
```

Comment: \\ is a \ escaped in Java, so the second group is actually `\d+`

Comment: @James in Stackoverflow for bold fonts i made it as `**[(.)(\\d+)(.)]**` So it displays as `(.)(\d+)(.)`. Modified it to `**[(.)(\\\d+)(.)]**`. Its now `(.)(\\d+)(.)`. Thanks for your observation. Please review it.

Comment: Sorry, you changed the wrong bit. In your explanation, you've put that the 2nd capturing group is \\d+ but it should be \d+ (one or more digits). This is because a \\ in a Java string is an escaped \